# How do I make NuGet aware of a specific version of a package while referencing a multi-targeted class library?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, multitargeting

We have three projects:

`WebApp.csproj`, ASP.NET WebForms app compiled against .NET Framework 2.0

`Api.csproj`, ASP.NET WebApi 2 compiled against .NET Framework 4.5

`Lib.csproj`, compiled against .NET Framework 2.0 and referenced by both of the projects above.

`Lib.csproj` has been recreated in the new .NET project format (the one used by .NET Core) and made to target both .NET Fw 2.0 and 4.5 with the `<TargetFrameworks>net20;net45</TargetFrameworks>` technique.

So far so good, I can reference different NuGet packages by writing the appropriate sections in `Lib.csproj` like so:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net20'">    
    <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="2.1.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net45'">
    <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="4.7.8.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

and I can point `Api.csproj` to the version of `Lib.csproj` targeting `net45`, like so:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\Lib\Lib.csproj" AdditionalProperties="TargetFramework=net45">
    <Project>{32e77bcf-152c-4b64-be37-a13f49cdcab6}</Project>
    <Name>Lib</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

The `net20` version references `NLog 2.1.0`, the `net45` one `NLog 4.7.8`.

The problem: now I want to use `NLog 4.7.8` in my `Api.csproj`, but when I click on `Manage Packages for Solution` on the solution that includes `Api.csproj` and `Lib.csproj`, the referenced version appears to be `2.1.0`.

I tried selecting both projects and installing it, however I rightly get an error because `NLog 4.7.8` is not compatible with `net20`.

So really, the problem is that NuGet does not seem to be aware that the project I'm referencing is a multi-target one, and only sees the version of NLog installed in the `net20` version even though `Api.csproj` is targeting the right "flavor" of `Lib.csproj` (and if I go and check the binaries, the version of NLog.dll that gets copied to the output folders is the right one for each of my targets).

I tried looking on the interwebs, but to no avail.

To be fair: the version of NLog that gets copied to `Api.csproj`'s `bin` folder is the right one, so it's not a showstopper. But it is mildly annoying, because NuGet shows the wrong version of my dependency, and then it's hard to tell what version we're actually using.

*For a bit of context*: this app is obviously ancient, at least `WebApp.csproj`. Due to performance reasons, we are making `Api.csproj` use `async/await`, and since that project references code that could be made async in `Lib.csproj` but obviously wouldn't compile under .NET 2, we chose to make `Lib.csproj` multi-targeted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `AdditionalProperties` here shouldn't be necessary:

```xml
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\Lib\Lib.csproj" AdditionalProperties="TargetFramework=net45">
    <Project>{32e77bcf-152c-4b64-be37-a13f49cdcab6}</Project>
    <Name>Lib</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

I strongly recommend updating all your projects to use SDK-style csproj format if possible. This isn't possible for legacy (pre-Core) web projects, which is the case for `WebApp.csproj` and `Api.csproj`. However, even those projects can use *some parts of* the newer csproj format.

Specifically, [they can use `PackageReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference). I assume your existing web projects are using `nuget.config`, but they can be changed to use `PackageReference` without actually making them SDK-style csprojs. NuGet has some issues with transitive dependencies when `nuget.config` is used, so I just recommend using `PackageReference` everywhere.

Comment: Wow, Mr. Async/Await himself replied! Thank you very much Stephen, I will definitely look into upgrading to `PackageReference` and see if that solves it. For what it's worth, that `AdditionalProperties` is the only way I could make the project reference the version targeting the right framework, maybe I'm missing something. It defaulted to picking up the net20 one, which is consistent with what I've been reading.

Comment: @s.m.: It *should* default to using the `net45` build, since that matches the `Api.csproj` target framework.

Comment: That's precisely what I thought, but it seemed to pick up the net20 flavor. I'll give it another shot tomorrow, today was busy. Thanks again, man :)